# Is there a way to disable exceptions in STL, or is using EASTL the only option?

Tags: c++, exception, stl, game-engine, c++17

I am currently developing a cross-platform game engine in C++ 17, and have encountered a problem with exceptions. After reading up on error handling in performance critical applications, I have come to the decision of not using exceptions in my project, replacing a throwing function with a function returning error info by a type similar to std::expected for trivial errors, and aborting when the encountered error is fatal. **What I am currently struggling with is retaining the ability to use the standard template library with exceptions disabled (as leaving exceptions turned on might cause problems when running the engine on consoles).** I have read that it is possible to turn all exceptions into aborts by compiling the standard template library with exceptions disabled, however I am not sure if this is a good cross-platform solution (especially since MSVC seems very uncooperative when trying to compile without exceptions). **One solution is to use EASTL instead, however I would prefer working with the standard, as it is, to my knowledge, better documented and up to date with modern cpp**.

---

**Is there a solution to my problem, or am I forced to use EASTL?**

Comment: I'm curious: what exactly are you trying to accomplish by turning exceptions off at the compiler level?

Comment: The standard does not provide for turning exceptions or any other feature of C++ on and off. All known compilers allow disabling exceptions with compile time switches. You can do it while using the standard library that comes with your compiler if you want to. What exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: For msvc just compile without /EHsc and define _HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0. I'm not sure why it doesn't automatically detect it.

Comment: @NicolBolas -- It this your question for the whole Gaming industry?

Answer (score 0):

Using CL.exe

MS STL works perfectly well with C++ exceptions disabled. If c++ exceptions are disabled MS STL raises structured exceptions instead.

If `_HAS_EXCEPTIONS == 0` or if `/EH` switch of any kind is not present or if `/kernel` switch, is used, keywords throw/try/catch do not compile any more. You are in the land of [SEH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/structured-exception-handling-c-cpp?view=msvc-160). SEH is intrinsic to Windows.

EASTL would be perfect OS-agnostic solution for you, but on Windows, EASTL does not use SEH. If `_HAS_EXCEPTIONS == 0`. It simply tries [EASTL_DEBUG_BREAK()](https://eastl.docsforge.com/master/api/EASTL_DEBUG_BREAK/).

At runtime, you use `_CPPUNWIND` to check if exceptions are enabled or not.
If `_CPPUNWIND` does not exist, keywords try/throw/catch, do not exist any more.